# How to upgrade page layout from SP2010 to SP2013?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, custom-masterpage

I am migrating some sites from SP2010 farm to SP2013. One of site collection contain a site content type page. When user create a new page in specific page library, it will generate a new page based on a page layout at `/sites/TestSite/_catalogs/masterpage/ABCpage.aspx`.

When I check the source code of `ABCpage.aspx`, I found it is using old library. For example,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

How do I change them and should I change?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the dll reference! goto here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

look for each one and change accordingly.

should look somthing like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

the aspx that you have is custom i presume that was migrated over and so would need to be changed as every time you create a site it would be referencing 2010 dlls. Most of the time the only thing you need to change is the version number (14 to 15) as the dll ID stays the same but just incase iv given you the location of the new GAC.

to change the file goto:

> /sites/TestSite/_catalogs/masterpage/

check out the file and download a copy:

> ABCpage.aspx

make changes within a text editor like notepad or notepad++. Then save the file and upload back in to:

> /sites/TestSite/_catalogs/masterpage/

overwite existing and make as major version and approve. all done

Comment: There are a hundred of old pages using old format. Do I need to change them and "should I change them?"

Answer (score 0):

You can update the assembly references to point to version 15 for SP2013 however, it may be ideal to take a copy of your current solution and upgrade it to 2013 using Visual Studio. This process should be automatic if you use VS2012+ and will update most references to 2013 from 2010.

For more info, see [here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions-to-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thanks for your link. I have refered his article to upgrade my solutions. However it doesn't cover how to upgrade a single page layout.

Comment: Why not upgrade a copy of the solution and then pull the updated page layout from that upgraded copy?? At least you will know that VS has upgraded the layout?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the problem, you can developed a feature receiver in C# which updates the Page Layouts and Master pages upon feature activations. The feature activation event goes through every single module which is to be provisioned via that specific feature and update the Page Layouts and Master Pages.

here is the link in how to implement:
http://falakmahmood.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-updating-masterpages.html