# How to migrate a sharepoint 2010 pagelayout to sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

I have custom page layouts in SP2010 and I am migrating to SP2013, and I want to use them in SP2013. I noticed the html/css structure is very different in 2013 page layouts. I was wondering if there is a way to still use my old ones in 2013?

Is there a conversion tool or something? Or do I have to manually rebuild them?

I found this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/21a9cad1-a8db-448f-9f12-75d10da402cf/migrating-custom-solutions-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin

But I have no idea what the solution is...

Comment: A couple of possible approaches include: use SharePoint Designer to export the files from one environment to the other (using the Export command, not a file copy/paste), or "Save as Template" from the browser ribbon on the 2010 site, then "Upload template" on 2013.. I've done the latter for pages and lists, but a caveat is that this content doesn't gain any of 2013's new features. (I templated a SP2007 list that someone else had templated into 2010, and it couldn't even connect to a filter. And since I don't know if you can even do this for page layouts, I'll just comment instead of answering.

Answer (score 1):

MSFT recomending that you should recreate pages layout in new version.

> When you upgrade your site collection to SharePoint 2013, these types
> of customizations will not work as is because the default CSS styles,
> themes, and master pages have changed. **Instead, you must re-create**
> your custom branding by using the new styles, themes, or master pages
> available in SharePoint 2013, and then apply the newly re-created
> design to the upgraded site collection.
> [Branding issues that may occur when upgrading to SharePoint 2013](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Branding-issues-that-may-occur-when-upgrading-to-SharePoint-2013-0c849002-cdf4-4843-9d4a-0a643a7c64f3)

their are couple of migration tools which help you to migrate the page layouts. i.e.[Migrate SharePoint Master Pages & Page Layouts Wisely](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/how-to-migrate-master-pages-and-page-layouts)

Also check this one: [How to upgrade page layout from SP2010 to SP2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111838/how-to-upgrade-page-layout-from-sp2010-to-sp2013)

Comment: I saw these but not sure how to do them.

Comment: with the tool it is easy as they mentioned, you can try it using their trial version....But other option do it from scratch in 2013....How you deployed the pages layout....just upload it in site collection....or you developed and packages in single WSp using studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default page layout for creating the pages,

Go to  [site settings] [look and feel] [Page layouts and site settings]  Under new page default setting, select the page layout you want.

After creating the page, you can edit the page and change the page layout

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5199ead5-ea85-475b-a62a-8deaa635d449/how-to-change-page-layouts-of-all-pages-from-a-2010-to-2013-migration?forum=sharepointdevelopment

http://expert-advice.org/sharepoint/step-step-guide-migrate-sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-2013/

In addition, you can use SharePoint designer->page layout to change it.